# How can I tell how many queries per second mysql is handling?

Tags: mysql

Is there a simple mysql command that can tell me how active our database is?

Answer (score 2):

I like [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) for this (I keep several instances running in a screen all the time), and [innotop](http://code.google.com/p/innotop/) is very helpful if you're using innodb tables.

Answer (score 0):

I like `mytop`; it's a bit of a pain in the butt to use, but seems to work well enough for the simple stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mysqladmin status
```

That'll do for one-off measurements. If you want a more long-term view of mysql's load, I'd recommend checking out [Munin](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmunin.projects.linpro.no%2F&ei=--tHS5X1OZC2NuL2nI8J&usg=AFQjCNG63E12jzDyN0U3E1Nt-wPfVZ0zGg). Out of the box, it comes configured with a mysql queries per second graph.

Comment: Let's hope munin's graphs aren't based off the qps rate coming out of mysqladmin, because that isn't exactly a good short-term average.

Comment: Heh, true. I'm sure it's looking at the "Questions" value and taking the delta between subsequent polls.